# What directory do you put .hs files in so you can load them using :l in GHCI?

Tags: haskell, windows-7, ghc, ghci

I am running GHCI 6.4 in Windows 7. I do not know what sub directory of the .\ghc\ directory to add .hs files to. Every time I try using :l it tells me that the file cannot be found. Has Anybody else run into this problem?

EDIT:  Thank you for your answers. Both of those look like they will work, but I ended up using the ":cd " command as per my professor's recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only used GHCi a little, but I've always been able to do `:l D:\Documents\Haskell\myscript.hs` with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a directory PATH to the search path with `:set -iPATH`.  After that, you can load files that are in that directory.